# How can I turn this if statement into a ternary (javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, jsx, ternary

I've written this if statement that returns jsx elements (react) and i was this to be full ternary (not only the one in the second scope:

jsx:

```
if (pageState === 'ready') {
      return (
        <>
          <Particles className="particles" params={params} />
          <Navigation isSignedIn={isSignedIn} onRouteChange={onRouteChange} />
          {route === 'home'
            ? <>
              <Rank name={this.state.user.name} entries={this.state.user.entries} />
              <LinkForm inputChange={onInputChange} onSubmit={onSubmit} />
              <ImageBox box={box} imageSrc={imageUrl} />
            </>
            : (
              route === 'signin'
                ? <SignIn loadUser={loadUser} onRouteChange={onRouteChange} />
                : <SignUp loadUser={loadUser} onRouteChange={onRouteChange} />
            )
          }
        </>
      )
    } else if (pageState === 'loading') {
      return (
        <>
          <Particles className="particles" params={params} />
          <Loader />
        </>
      )
    }
```

Comment: Well, you have `if / elseif` instead of `if / else`, ternary operators are not very well suited for this

Comment: Why? You already have a nested ternary in your code; adding another would make your code more difficult to read and maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not recommending this because it is much less readable.  Additionally, in order to use a conditional return, you *must* return something.  So you'll need the final 'else' statement or keep on with your current approach.

```
return (pageState === 'ready') ?
  (
    <>
      <Particles className="particles" params={params} />
      <Navigation isSignedIn={isSignedIn} onRouteChange={onRouteChange} />
      {route === 'home'
        ? <>
          <Rank name={this.state.user.name} entries={this.state.user.entries} />
          <LinkForm inputChange={onInputChange} onSubmit={onSubmit} />
          <ImageBox box={box} imageSrc={imageUrl} />
        </>
        : (
          route === 'signin'
            ? <SignIn loadUser={loadUser} onRouteChange={onRouteChange} />
            : <SignUp loadUser={loadUser} onRouteChange={onRouteChange} />
        )
      }
    </>
  )
: (pageState === 'loading') ?
  (
    <>
      <Particles className="particles" params={params} />
      <Loader />
    </>
  )
: // You need a final 'else' condition
```